# How can I download the access log to my AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, logging

I need to download an access log to my Amazon AWS console, possibly with IP address info or locations.

I don't need the logs of a specific AWS service but only the access logs to the console (https://aws.amazon.com/it/console/).

Is there a service that I can use to retrieve it?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/it/cloudtrail/).

To search for all console logins, follow these steps:

- Go to the CloudTrail Console.
- Click on `Event History` in the left menu.
- In `Lookup Attributes`, choose `Event Name` and type `ConsoleLogin` in the text field.
- *(Optional)* Customize the time range.
- Click on the `Download Events` button and choose the format of the export (JSON or CSV)